# Python3-BeautifulSoup , need to extract first table by adding additional field from div block to all the below values upto next div block

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

Using Python3 Beautiful soup i need to extract the first table from the source : https://docs.snowflake.com/en/release-notes/requirements.html
by adding a newfield named variation to every output. That variation field is being extracted from `<div>` inside `<td>`.
The values of variation would be (CLI (Command Line Interface) , Connectors and Drivers , Other )

Example of Required output :

```
Variation , Client , MinimumVersion
CLI , SnowSQL ,1.2.0
Connectors and Drivers , Snowflake Connector for Python , 1.9.1
Connectors and Drivers , Snowflake SQLAlchemy (for Python) , 1.0.8
Other , SnowflakeDB backend for dplyr , 0.3.0-rc1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = "https://docs.snowflake.com/en/release-notes/requirements.html"
html = requests.get(url)
html.encoding = html.apparent_encoding
df = pd.read_html(html.text, flavor="bs4")[0]
df.to_csv("first_table.csv", index=False, encoding="utf-8")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: No, the output expected is different. CLI value should be included for row 3 and Connectors and Drivers value should be included from 5 to 14 and Other value for 16 and 17th row.

Comment: The output of client type in bold should be added to the rest of the values it belongs to. kindly help.

Comment: By using the above code , I am still getting the output with special characters. Eg : MinimumÂ VersionÂ [1]Â [2]

Comment: Open the file with the correct encoding (`utf-8`).

Comment: Opening the file in the correct encoding format helped. But as said in the earlier comments the output expected is different.  CLI value should be included for row 3 and Connectors and Drivers value should be included from 5 to 14 and Other value for 16 and 17th row